# Fatal error: ob_end_flush() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]:

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: ob_end_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /home/filmkor1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3269

[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: Do you know what code is calling `wp_ob_end_flush_all` or otherwise triggering this error?

Comment: Please always post code here with the editor. Use the `{}` toolbar button or ctl-k to format it as a code block, which provides syntax highlighting. An image of code is less useful to us.

Comment: No dude :( i dont know :S

Comment: http://www.filmkorku.org/answers/ please check this url dude.

Comment: function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
 $levels = ob_get_level();
 for ($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++)
  ob_end_flush();
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the exact same error...went through every plugin one at a time.  Apparently All in One SEO Plugin...updated their plugin to add a pro version that you pay for...and this is what happens if you have the free version.

Hope that helps you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. 
I just increased memory limit and the error has gone. I increased memory limit by writing this:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

I add this code in `wp-config.php` file